# Pearson correlation between adjacent columns in a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pearson-correlation

let say I have a dataframe of 10 columns.

now I want  to quickly calculate the relation between each column and its following column.

so pearson r of column 1 and 2, of column 2 and 3, of column 3 and 4 and so on.

is there a quick way for me to do that?

thank you!

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.corr`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) for Pearson correlation and [`numpy.diag`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html) to extract the values of interest. Let me show you a toy example with 5 columns (for simplicity):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(3,5)))

pcorr = df.corr()
np.diag(pcorr, 1)
```

and you get:

df:

```
    0   1   2   3   4
0   7   9   0   0   9
1   9   2   9   9   0
2   2   8   5   9   2
```

pcorr:

```
        0            1          2            3          4
0   1.000000    -0.622693   0.215274    -0.240192   0.029344
1   -0.622693   1.000000    -0.898170   -0.609994   0.763857
2   0.215274    -0.898170   1.000000    0.896258    -0.969816
3   -0.240192   -0.609994   0.896258    1.000000    -0.977356
4   0.029344    0.763857    -0.969816   -0.977356   1.000000
```

your values of interest:

```
array([-0.62269252, -0.89817029,  0.89625816, -0.97735555])
```